# oauth2 in php - specified in curl

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I am trying to implement the authentication as specified here : https://api.thermosmart.com/apidoc/
I get through the first steps and get an authorization code back. I need to exchange that for an acces_token. The step in curl is specified as:
    # 4. Exchange authorization code for Access token (read out the code from the previous response)
    curl -k -u client123:client-secret -b cookie.txt -vd "grant_type=authorization_code&code=HPOfdlCbiZ1tI4Lv&redirect_uri=..." "url for token"

My code in PHP:

```
$curl = curl_init( 'url for token' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
$userpwd = $oauth2_client_id.":".$oauth2_secret; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'redirect_uri' => $oauth2_redirect,
    'code' => $code, // The code from the previous request
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
) ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$auth = curl_exec( $curl );
}
$secret = json_decode($auth);
$access_key = $secret->access_token;

echo "OAuth2 server provided access token: " . $access_key;
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have struggled with the same question (for Qt Quick application, but maybe it can help you)... 
(Asking for help resulted in quick response from ThermoSmart...

My code to exchange access token for authorization code:

`req.open("POST", "https://api.thermosmart.com/oauth2/token", true, client_id, client_secret);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send("grant_type=authorization_code"+"&code="+ authorization_code + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri);`